# I am making a traffic light controller using a moore circuit with a N/S light and and E/W light and my output keeps coming out as all X's

Tags: verilog

[Here are the parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdT1x.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdT1x.png)

I have ran the files and checked the gtk wave and I can't figure out where my wiring is going wrong. I am using a moore circuit with one input. I just need someone to help me figure out where I am messing up the wiring.
Thanks

module traffic(T, CLK, GN, YN, RN, GE, YE, RE);

```
// inputs
input CLK;
input T;

// outputs
output reg GN;
output reg YN;
output reg RN;
output reg GE;
output reg YE;
output reg RE;

// flip-flops 
reg gN = 1'b1;
reg yN = 1'b0;
reg rN = 1'b0;
reg gE = 1'b0;
reg yE = 1'b0;
reg rE = 1'b1;

// Wires
wire gNplus = 1'b1; 
wire yNplus = 1'b0; 
wire rNplus = 1'b0; 
wire gEplus = 1'b0;
wire yEplus = 1'b0;
wire rEplus = 1'b1;

// Next State and Output
assign CLK = 0;
always @(posedge CLK) 
begin
    gN <= gNplus;
    yN <= yNplus;
    rN <= rNplus;
    gE <= gEplus;
    yE <= yEplus;
    rE <= rEplus;

    GN <= gN;
    YN <= yN;
    RN <= rN;
    GE <= gE;
    YE <= yE;
    RE <= rE;

end 

// combinational logic
assign gNplus = ~T * ~yN;
assign yNplus = gN;
assign rNplus = (rN * T) | yN;
assign gEplus = ~T * ~yE;
assign yEplus = gE;
assign rEplus = (rE * T) | yE;
```

endmodule

Test bench
`include "traffic.v"` timescale 10ns/1ns

module traffic_test;

```
reg T; 

wire GN;
wire YN;
wire RN; 
wire GE; 
wire YE;
wire RE;

traffic UUT(.T(T), .CLK(CLK), .GN(gNplus), .YN(yNplus), .RN(rNplus), .GE(gEplus), .YE(yEplus), .RE(rEplus));

reg CLK = 1'b1;
always  
begin
    CLK = ~CLK;
    #5;
end


initial begin
    T = 0;
    forever begin
        #20 T = ~T;
    end

end

initial begin
        $display("START OF TEST");
        $dumpfile("traffic.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0, traffic_test);
        
        $display("T | GN YN RN | GE YE RE");
    
        for (integer i = 0;i < 11;i =i + 1) 
        begin
            {T} = i;
            $display("%b |  %b  %b  %b |  %b  %b  %b", T, gNplus, yNplus, rNplus, gEplus, yEplus, rEplus);
        end
        $finish;
        $display("END OF TEST");
    end
```

endmodule

Answer (score 0):

You code does not have proper reset and multiple drivers on your wires.

The following statement is **not** a simple initialization statement.

```
wire gNplus = 1'b1; 
wire yNplus = 1'b0; 
...
```

Those statements are same as

```
wire gNplus;
assign gNplus = 1'b1; 
wire yNplus;
assign yNplus = 1'b0;
```

Now you have another set of statements:

```
assign gNplus = ~T * ~yN;
assign yNplus = gN;
...
```

You are driving the same wires twice with **different** values. The resulting value will be `X`.

The following is not necessarily a proper initialization of the register. First of all it is not always synthesizable. Secondly it is done before time 0 of simulation and any side effects of initial simulation step can re-write them with wrong values. You should come up with a reset sequence for the flop.

```
reg gN = 1'b1;
reg yN = 1'b0;
...
```

A couple of other side notes.

- What does this statement do in your code: `assign CLK = 0;`? You initialize your clock in test bench to `1`. It would be better to do it in an initial block though.
- you declare your CLK signal in the test bench after you use it. This way the verilog can use a default type, which usually is a `wire`.